# Cursor not populating while using max in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a database like following

```
datetime    value
date1        200
date2        230
date3        210
date4        240
date5        220
```

I find out the rowid for the column of which I want to dynamically find out the max value for the 2 rows above
Say I found 4 for date4, I want to calculate the maximum of values 230,210 and 240 which is 240

I give the following command

```
c.execute("SELECT MAX(value) FROM TABLE LIMIT "+str(rowid-2)+",3")
print(c.fetchall())
```

The problem is cursor doesn't populate and returns an empty list while in

```
c.execute("SELECT value FROM TABLE LIMIT "+str(rowid-2)+",3")
print(c.fetchall())
```

it returns the correct values of the 3 rows (3 tuples in a list). Can I not use limit with max? What is the problem? Do I have to make another int column equivalent to rowid for querying well and use an order by numberingColumn or is there a better solution?

Comment: Your first query returns a single row, which you say to skip with that offset of 3. Thus, no rows are returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Shawn

```
c.execute("SELECT MAX(TEMPVALUE) FROM (SELECT value AS TEMPVALUE FROM TABLE LIMIT "+str(rowid+2)+",3)")
```

solved the problem!